# Class is not defined at captcha.js:25 Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha

We have a problem with the Captcha in Magento 1.9. There is an error with JS:
[image: JS Errors]
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: did you find the solution?